# Change URL of Prerequisites from ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, prerequisites, setup.exe

I want to know if is possible to change the Update URL of deployed ClickOnce application modifying the deployed files.

I know that the application have two parts:

1. The compiled files with .application and .deploy files
2. The setup.exe and the folders and files of each prerequisite

I was able to change url and to introduce new files, doing properly modifications of .application and .deploy files and resigning with the certificate.

But I don't know how to change the URL of server of inside of the setup.exe. There are any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this post: [Packaging a ClickOnce Server Deployment](http://proactivelogic.com/blog/index.php/2006/09/30/packaging-a-clickonce-server-deployment/)

The next command line is used to modify the url of setup.exe (the setup.exe modifies to it self to use new url specified in parameter):

```
setup.exe /url=http://myserverhostname/
```

I hope this reply helps someone.